# Just setting the last parameter from form to action when populating, why?

Tags: java, forms, struts2, setter, populate

This is my form in jsp. When I submit it, in the server log I can see all the parameters with their values, but when I do a println of the object just the last one (alphabetically) was set.

```
<s:form action="contactos-modificar" method="POST" name="editarContacto">
    <s:hidden name="contactoModif.id" value="%{contactoEditar.id}"/>
    <div id="top">
        <label for="contactoModif.nombre">Nombre</label><br/>
        <s:textfield cssClass="large" name="contactoModif.nombre" value="%{contactoEditar.nombre}" />
    </div>

    <div id="izq">
        <label for="contactoModif.lugarNac">Lugar de nacimiento</label><br/>
        <s:textfield cssClass="large" name="contactoModif.lugarNac" value="%{contactoEditar.lugarNac}" />
        <br/>
        <label for="contactoModif.empresa">Empresa</label><br/>
        <s:textfield cssClass="large" name="contactoModif.empresa" value="%{contactoEditar.empresa}"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="localizacion">Localización</label><br/>
        <s:textfield cssClass="large" name="contactoModif.localizacion" value="%{contactoEditar.localizacion}"/>
    </div>

    <div id="dcha">
        <label for="contactoModif.fechaNac">Fecha de nacimiento</label><br/>
        <s:textfield cssClass="large" name="contactoModif.fechaNac" value="%{contactoEditar.fechaNac}"/>
        </br>
        <label for="contactoModif.puesto">Puesto</label><br/>
        <s:textfield cssClass="large" name="contactoModif.puesto" value="%{contactoEditar.puesto}"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="contactoModif.direccion">Dirección</label><br/>
        <s:textarea cssClass="direccion" name="contactoModif.direccion"><s:property value="contactoEditar.direccion"/></s:textarea>
    </div>

    <div id="bot">
        <label for="contactoModif.notas">Notas</label><br/>
        <s:textarea cssClass="notas" name="contactoModif.notas"><s:property value="contactoEditar.notas"/></s:textarea>
        <br/>

        <s:submit cssClass="submit" value="Guardar cambios"/>
    </div>
```

The server log:

```
2012-12-08 12:39:42,148 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:68 - intercept '//contactos-modificar' { 
2012-12-08 12:39:42,149 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:68 - applied invocation context locale=es_ES
2012-12-08 12:39:42,150 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:68 - before Locale=es_ES
2012-12-08 12:39:42,181 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=struts]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,184 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.debug:68 - Resource bundles reloaded
2012-12-08 12:39:42,188 DEBUG org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.debug:68 - Bypassing //contactos-modificar
2012-12-08 12:39:42,188 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.debug:68 - Setting static parameters {}
2012-12-08 12:39:42,189 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.debug:68 - Setting params NONE
2012-12-08 12:39:42,189 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.debug:68 - Setting params contactoModif.direccion => [ fffffff ] contactoModif.empresa => [ ccccccc ] contactoModif.fechaNac => [ 11-11-1111 ] contactoModif.id => [ 124 ] contactoModif.localizacion => [ dddddd ] contactoModif.lugarNac => [ bbbbbb ] contactoModif.nombre => [ aaaaaa ] contactoModif.notas => [ ggggggg ] contactoModif.puesto => [ eeeeeee ] 
2012-12-08 12:39:42,189 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,190 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: direccion
2012-12-08 12:39:42,190 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,191 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [direccion] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,191 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [direccion] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,192 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,192 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [string]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,193 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter] with name [string], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,193 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,262 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: empresa
2012-12-08 12:39:42,263 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,263 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [empresa] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,264 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [empresa] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,264 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,265 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [string]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,266 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter] with name [string], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,267 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,268 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: fechaNac
2012-12-08 12:39:42,268 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,269 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [fechaNac] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,269 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [fechaNac] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,269 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,270 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [string]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,270 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter] with name [string], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,271 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,272 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: id
2012-12-08 12:39:42,272 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,273 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [id] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,273 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [id] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,274 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,274 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [number]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,275 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter] with name [number], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,275 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,276 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: localizacion
2012-12-08 12:39:42,329 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,329 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [localizacion] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,330 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [localizacion] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,331 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,331 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [string]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,331 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter] with name [string], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,333 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,334 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: lugarNac
2012-12-08 12:39:42,334 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,335 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [lugarNac] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,335 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [lugarNac] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,336 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,337 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [string]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,337 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter] with name [string], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,338 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,338 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: nombre
2012-12-08 12:39:42,339 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,339 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [nombre] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,340 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [nombre] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,340 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,341 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [string]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,341 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter] with name [string], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,342 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,343 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: notas
2012-12-08 12:39:42,343 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,395 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [notas] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,395 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [notas] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,396 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,397 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [string]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,397 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter] with name [string], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,398 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:68 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@c6ede2], property=contactoModif]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,399 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Property: puesto
2012-12-08 12:39:42,400 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - Class: org.letter.ltr.model.ContactoPerfil
2012-12-08 12:39:42,400 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - field-level type converter for property [puesto] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,401 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - global-level type converter for property [puesto] = none found
2012-12-08 12:39:42,401 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:68 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@78e377]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,402 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Creating converter with name [string]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,402 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.debug:68 - Converter of Type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter] with name [string], created!
2012-12-08 12:39:42,404 DEBUG org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.debug:68 - Validating //contactos-modificar with method modificarContacto.
2012-12-08 12:39:42,424 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.debug:68 - Invoking validate() on action org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad
2012-12-08 12:39:42,425 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrefixMethodInvocationUtil.debug:68 - cannot find method [validateModificarContacto] in action [org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,425 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrefixMethodInvocationUtil.debug:68 - cannot find method [validateDoModificarContacto] in action [org.letter.ltr.action.ContactosAction@17805ad]
2012-12-08 12:39:42,426 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.debug:68 - Executing action method = modificarContacto
```

Just "contactoModif.puesto" was set to the object. The other ones are empty.

This is my object:

```
public class ContactoPerfil {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int id=0;
private String nombre="";
private String fechaNac="";
private String lugarNac="";
private String empresa="";
private String puesto="";
private String direccion="";
private String localizacion="";
private String notas="";                 


public int getId(){
    return id;
}
public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}    
public String getFechaNac(){
    return fechaNac;
}
public String getLugarNac(){
    return lugarNac;
}
public String getEmpresa(){
    return empresa;
}
public String getPuesto(){
    return puesto;
}
public String getDireccion(){
    return direccion;
}
public String getLocalizacion(){
    return localizacion;
}
public String getNotas(){
    return notas;
}

public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public void setFechaNac(String fechaNac){
    this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
}
public void setLugarNac(String lugarNac){
    this.lugarNac = lugarNac;
}
public void setEmpresa(String empresa){
    this.empresa = empresa;
}
public void setPuesto(String puesto){
    this.puesto = puesto;
}
public void setDireccion(String direccion){
    this.direccion = direccion;
}
public void setLocalizacion(String localizacion){
    this.localizacion = localizacion;
}
public void setNotas(String notas){
    this.notas = notas;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    //code
}
```

}

I tried with "contactoModif.nombre, "contactoModif.empresa" and "contactoModif.lugarNac" and the same happened, just "contactoModif.nombre" was set (another time the last one alphabetically because it's the last one converted by struts2).

In the action:

```
public class ContactosAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware,ServletRequestAware{
private ContactoPerfil contactoModif;

@Action(value="contactos-modificar",
        results={
        @Result(name="success", type="stream", params={"contentType","text/html","inputName","inputStream"}),
        @Result(name="error", type="stream", params={"contentType","text/html","inputName","inputStream"})}
        )
public String modificarContacto() throws Exception{
    //code
}

public void setContactoModif(ContactoPerfil c){
    this.contactoModif=c;
}
}
```

Struts version: 2.3.4

I need help, it's driving me crazy, it's very important for me to solve this, if I can't do it using the struts2 way I suppose I will use an html form and getServletRequest().

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know why in that way doesn't work, but I tried with this:

```
<label for="contactoModif.nombre">Nombre</label><br/>
<input type="text" class="large" name="contactoModif.nombre" value="<s:property value="contactoEditar.nombre"/>"/>
```

In the action:

```
public ContactoPerfil getContactoModif(){
    return contactoModif;
}
```

and now it works, I receive all the fields of the form and all are being stored in the object.
I just changed the fields and added the "get" method (I supposed just the "set" method was neccessary to get the values from the form), the rest of the code is the same.

PS: thank you MohanaRao SV, for editing my code to show colors and make it more clear.

Comment: It has to get the ContactoModif in order to call setAnything on it. I suspect without the get it was instantiating a new one for each set, but that's a guess at the moment.

Comment: I tried without the "getContactoModif()" method and yeah probably you're right because it doesn't work, even with the new input fields (they were not the problem then). Well, I thought just the "set" method was neccessary but it seems I was wrong. Thank you.